# Use *_get_instance_private() macro in gdb debugger

Tags: gdb, glib

glib generates a macro `x_get_instance_private()` for type `x`.

When debugging using `gdb`, I cannot call macros.

How do I view the instance private data?  The function I'm debugging does get the instance private data, but the variable which holds it has been `<optimized out>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `g_type_class_get_instance_private_offset`.

Based on sourcejedi answer, for NMManager (NetworkManager):

```
(gdb)  p *( (NMManagerPrivate *) ((char *) manager
              + g_type_class_get_instance_private_offset(
                          ((GTypeInstance *)manager)->g_class )))
```

This works when the private is not exactly before the object. Checked on
NMManager where the layout is not standard GObject.

Answer (score 2):

> When debugging using gdb, I cannot call macros.

Note that if you compile with `-g3`, then gcc will put macro bodies into the debug info, and gdb will let you use them in expressions.

That said, gdb only understands the "expression" subset of C -- so if the macro introduces a new scope or does other non-trivial stuff, then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Example for `GsShell` (gnome-software).  I have a `GObject` called `object`.  I discovered by experiment: the private data is stored before the `GObject`.

`(gdb) p *( (*GsShellPrivate) ((char *) object - sizeof(GsShellPrivate)) )`

Comment: AFAIK this is guaranteed for any type defined using `G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE `.